# How can I track every function call in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am developing a node js application in which there are 4 .js files each containing a class like this -

A.js ->

```
Class A{constructor(){}
func1(){}
}
```

B.js ->

```
Class B{constructor(){}
func2(){}
}
```

C.js ->

```
Class C{constructor(){}
func3(){}
}
```

D.js ->

```
Class D{constructor(){}
func4(){}
}
```

Now I want to track/log that which class imported which class and invoked what function without making much changes(if possible) in the files.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing is to get the class instance from outside, replace the function with your function that log and call the original function.